# sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters SQL Server 2005 running every 20 seconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

A little background info:

We are running SQL Server 2005 SP2 on a server with Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2.

When I run profiler I notice that `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters` is running every 20 seconds.

Here is what the profiler is running every 20 seconds:

```
SELECT N'Testing Connection...'
go
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_get_perf_counters
go
```

What I have done so far:

- I have deleted all the demo alerts on the system.

Possible answers:

- I was wondering if a service pack 3 or 4 on 2005 might fix this issue?
- or is there something I can set in the registry or in sql itself?
- or is there a patch for Windows Server 2003 that might help?

Comment: Need more information. Are you saying these queries are coming from profiler, or that you notice them in profiler? You said "...profiler is running..." so just want to clarify. Talk about the other columns in your trace, such as hostname, program name, etc. Maybe someone has perfmon or some other monitoring tool up on their workstation on an aggressive polling interval and went home for the day.

Comment: That all said, you shouldn't still be on SP2, it is no longer supported. You should have moved to at least SP3 but SP4 is your better bet. Once you have tested that it doesn't break your app, etc., of course.

Comment: I'm seeing this in SQL Server 2017. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1):

Does it matter, unless it is sucking resources? As I understand it (from some searches), it will run anyway.

There is an [MS Connect item for SQL Server 2008](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/536354/execute-msdb-dbo-sp-sqlagent-get-perf-counters-hogs-cpu-although-no-alerts-enabled#details) for CPU usage, but it looks unresolved